# Create fork from repository on github but in new pull request not find my fork

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I have made a modification of this https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification repository and when I try to make a new pull request in its repository I press compare forks and my fork doesn't appear ...

What am i doing wrong?

My fork is this: https://github.com/cookienawer/react-native-push-notification

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a pull request in your forked repository. When creating this pull request, you need to select merge with upstream.

Here are the basic steps to create a pull request in an open-source repo.

1. Fork the repository.
2. Create a branch and make the necessary changes.
3. Create a pull request on your branch and select merge to upstream master.
4. Submit the pull request for review.

You can find more information [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork).

Comment: I dont' understand... When I try to create a pull request in my branch appear only a brach... Then, the comparison always returns the same, because it is comparing the same branch

Comment: Looks like you haven't forked the repo correctly. It looks to me as though you've cloned the repo and created a new repo under your username. I would suggest you use the fork button on the original repo.

Comment: I had read that I had to create a repository and then vingulate it with a branch or something. Now I have not had any problems. Thank you.